# How to find out the relative path to upload image in php?

Tags: php, relative-path, image-uploading

I have a problem to find out the relative path to 
upload the images to other directories

**target directory**

```
htdocs/dt3/tadi/adm/dim/dim_images/tadi_user_images/
```

**source directory**

```
htdocs/dt3/tadi/adm/cbt/uploadfile.php
```

### uploadfile.php

```
<html>
    <form method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileimg1" ><input type="submit" name="upload">
    </form>
</html>


<?php
    $dirname = "/dt3/tadi/adm/dim/dim_images/tadi_user_images/";    

    $of = $_FILES['fileimg1']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($of, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $changename3 = time() * 24 * 60;
    $image_name3 = "timage_" . $changename3 . "." . $ext;

    $final_pathdir = $dirname . $image_name3;
    $suc = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileimg1']['tmp_name'], $final_pathdir);

    if ($suc > 0) 
    {
        echo "Image uploaded successfully"; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error : " . $_FILES['filimg1']['error'];
    }
?>
```

I tried out some of the paths, I didnt got any solution for that.
How can I upload images to that path?

`htdocs/dt3/tadi/adm/dim/dim_images/tadi_user_images/`

With relative path only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you could do

```
$dirname = dirname(__FILE__)."/../dim/dim_images/tadi_user_images/"
```

Comment: +1 nice patch .. but might become ugly in future as system grows .... better still he should just define `image upload path`